# Should a full stop punctuation be used in Abbreviations?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

I've noticed a full stop (period) after "UTC" on the [Enthusiast badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/enthusiast) page. In my understanding, the presence or absence of the period after the abbreviation doesn't seem to affect the meaning.

Are there any style guides that recommend using a period in abbreviations? I'm curious to know the conventions in this context.

**Screenshot for reference:**

> [image: Abbreviation with full stop]

**In a plain text:**

> Visit the site each day for 30 consecutive days. (Days are counted in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).).

Comment: It's marking the end of a sentence - the one in the brackets - and would be present whether or not there was an abbreviation before it. However, the full stop _after_ the brackets probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: What @SteveMelnikoff said. Except *the full stop **after** the brackets **definitely** shouldn't be there.* The entirety of the bracketed "parenthetical" element must be capable of being removed without affecting the validity of what's left (that's why its terminating full stop goes *inside* the brackets). If ***Days*** within the brackets hadn't been capitalised, the period before the opening bracket would have to be removed - but then the period *inside* the brackets would be unwanted!

Comment: This is something that's changed in my lifetime. When I was at school it would have been U.T.C. or N.A.T.O.  Today its the norm to treat strings of capital letters abbreviating something as a word, with no periods. The fact that it's a string of capitals is quite enough to indicate what it is.

Comment: And the 'in' is a trifle unusual too - I think I would have written 'using' instead, or maybe 'with'.

Comment: @nigel222 Agreed: capitals provide sufficient indication of an abbreviation, making a full stop redundant — and so we tend not to use the full stop there, to avoid ambiguity with its other functions.  That's why lower-case abbreviations such as ‘p.m.’ and ‘etc.’ still need a full stop — and why those are awkward and becoming rarer.  (‘etc.’ doesn't work in upper case, which is why I prefer using the more concise ‘&c’ instead.  But I gather it's not universally understood…)

Comment: @nigel222 - me too, though I don't miss them, they feel better without. There's also a tendency to call any abbreviation an acronym, where that use to be reserved for those you pronounce rather than spell; scuba, laser, NATO, NASA etc. Such as HHGTTG are still abbreviations to me, not acronyms.

Comment: @MikeB - Why? We count weeks *in* days, though I do complex arithmetic *with*, *on* or *using* my fingers.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.  Because UTC is a 'system', not a measure. Would you say "Days are counted in GMT." ?

Comment: @MikeB - in this context yes. It's short, to the point & gets the message across. What they mean is that day 'boundaries' are at UTC 0:00, but that's way too much to be bothered explaining in full.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. _HHGTTG_ **is** an abbreviation – acronyms are a strict subset of abbreviations. The word for the specific type of abbreviation which is pronounced by spelling out each individual letter is _initialism_.

Comment: @nigel222 I'm wondering how old you are; IBM has been going without periods since at least 1946: https://1000logos.net/ibm-logo/ . Granted, that's a logo, but still.

Comment: @Acccumulation Well into my 60s. Technical writers were the first to drop the periods. I was commenting on ordinary documents (like essays at school. I remember getting corrected for NATO without periods). Also at some point IBM became officially named IBM, not International Business Machines. Don't know when.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to your *actual question*, as mentioned elsewhere, is that UTC [nor any capitalised abbreviation in similar form] does not take a full-stop [period].

However… the sentence as written in the badge description is actually wrong, because it *appears* to give UTC a stop… then gives the sentence another stop, outside the brackets.

Because the entire sentence is enclosed within the brackets, the one *inside* is correct and ends the sentence. The one *outside* the brackets is spurious - and incorrect.

Comment: If you remove the one after UTC, it **becomes** accurate. So, that's enough.

Comment: @Lambie - no it doesn't. The one *inside* the bracket is correct. The entire sentence is inside, so the stop should be too. The one *outside* is wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah, the other way round. Right.

Answer (score 7):

The full stop (period) does not apply to UTC. It applies to the sentence UTC is contained in.

UTC does not contain a full stop.

[Definition of UTC](https://www.space.com/what-is-utc.html)

The sentence inside the brackets takes the period, not UTC.

Comment: That's kind of half-right, but there's a bigger issue.